# How to addmessage from a trigger to a visualforce page

Tags: apex, trigger, error-messages, before-trigger, pagemessages

I have a visualforce page with a controller extention. This page has some inputfields where

> I want to send a waring on the page before insert if the fielsd are filled in incorrectly.

I am using a trigger but this redirects my to the standar errorpage of SF.

> How can I addmessage to the VFP from the trigger instead of an error message so the message is shown on the VFP page with input fields

Here is my trigger:

```
trigger accountSearchTrg on Contact (before insert,before update) {
    List<Account> CheckAcc =[SELECT id, (SELECT Splits__c FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE id IN (SELECT AccountId
    FROM Contact  WHERE Splits__c=true)];

    for (Contact c : Trigger.New) {
        if(CheckAcc.size()>1) {             
            c.AddError('Not Possible');
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: I would worry about fixing your trigger first. As written, it does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use ApexPages.Message in your trigger.
- set a static variable in ControllerExtension before DML.
- Add  to Visualforce page.

see following pseudocode

```
for (Contact c : Trigger.New) {
    if(CheckAcc.size()>1)
 {
     if(ControllerExtension.staticVar != null)// code won't be invoked from standard layout
     {   
         ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error: Invalid Input.');
         ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
     }
     else
    {
        c.AddError('Not Possible');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Besides the probable problems with your trigger's logic, you shouldn't be trying to add a page message within a trigger. Instead, modify your page's controller as appropriate, usually by using ApexPages.addMessages():

```
try {
    update contactList;
} catch(DMLException e) {
    ApexPages.addMessages(e);
}
```

This will prevent the default error screen and allow you to present the errors in an `apex:pageMessages` element.