# How to get an Apex Class (not controller) error message to display on a VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

So we have a tool that manages a specific service ticket group, the VF page has its own controller with the account being the standard controller. But the case Apex class handler (we do most of the 'trigger' work in the handler) pops an error during a case record creation when we use this VF page....the problem is the VF page, on save, does a redirect to the newly created record....in this case it's null because the record wasn't created due to the case handler error.

Case handler:

```
public static void validationCheckForDuplicateCustomerTicket(List<Case> triggerNew){

    Set<String> setCustomerTicketIds = new Set<String>();
    Set<Id> setAccountIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> setCaseIDs = new Set<Id>();

    for(Case varCase :triggerNew){
        if(varCase.CustomerTicketID__c <> Null && varCase.AccountID <> Null){
            setCustomerTicketIDs.add(varCase.CustomerTicketID__c);
            setAccountIDs.add(varCase.AccountID);
            setCaseIDs.add(varCase.Id);
        }
    }

    //Retrieve all existing cases for the list of Accounts, and Customer Ticket IDs.
    List<Case> listExistingCustomerTickets = [SELECT Id, AccountID, CustomerTicketId__c, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE CustomerTicketID__c in :setCustomerTicketIDs AND AccountID in :setAccountIds AND Id NOT IN :setCaseIDs];        

    Map<String, Case> mapExistingAccCustTicketIDs = new Map<String,Case>();

    for(Case varCase :listExistingCustomerTickets){
            mapExistingAccCustTicketIDs.put(varCase.AccountID+varCase.CustomerTicketID__c, varCase);            
    }

    for(Case varCase :triggerNew){            
        if(varCase.AccountID <> Null && varCase.CustomerTicketID__c <> NULL && mapExistingAccCustTicketIDs.containskey(varCase.AccountID+varCase.CustomerTicketID__c)){            
            Trigger.new[0].adderror('A Ticket has already been created for this Account and Customer Ticket ID. '+mapExistingAccCustTicketIDs.get(varCase.AccountID+varCase.CustomerTicketID__c).CaseNumber);                 
        }
    }

}
```

Error is at the bottom

VF page section below the the oncomplete.

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!systemInfoRequest}"> 
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-01">
                    <abbr class="slds-required" style="color: red;" title="required">*</abbr> Service Request Type :</label>
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <apex:inputField styleClass="slds-select" required="true" value="{!objTicket.Information_Request_Type__c}" label="Service Request Type"/>
                    </div>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                </div>                                               
                <br/><br/>
                <div> 
                    <apex:outputPanel id="pnlTtkId">
                        <apex:inputHidden id="ticketNumberId" value="{!ticketNumber}"/>
                        <apex:inputHidden id="ticketId" value="{!ticketId}"/>                           
                    </apex:outputPanel>  
                     <apex:commandButton value="Finish" action="{!SaveTicket}" status="actionStatusID" rerender="pnlTtkId,msgId" oncomplete="changeSubTabName();" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--brand" />
                </div>                                        
                </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>             
        <apex:outputpanel >
            <apex:actionStatus id="actionStatusID">
                <apex:facet name="start">
                <div style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; opacity: 0.25; z-index: 1000; background-color: black;">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
                <div style="position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; z-index: 1001; margin: 15% 50%">
                    <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 2px; background-color: #fff; width: 125px; margin-left: -60px;">
                        <img src="/img/loading.gif" />
                        <span>Please Wait...</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </apex:facet>
            </apex:actionStatus>
        </apex:outputpanel>

        <br/><br/><br/>

</div>
```

Here's the oncomplete function it's JS

```
function changeSubTabName(){
                var t = j$('[id$="ticketNumberId"]').val();              
                if(t){
                    sforce.console.setTabTitle(t);

               }                      
                    detailPage();


            }
```

The detiaPage() method is just a pagereference to the new record redirect. On the controller.

What i wanted to do is make the case handler an extension...cant due that because theres a lack of public myControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)........Is there anyway to catch error output of the apex class and push that into a string and then do a check somewhere in the JS function to stop the save/redirect while having the error display on the screen?

i'm thinking of being lazy and simply doing a null check in the JS function for the new record ID before a redirect happens.

Comment: how you have written in the controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193240/how-to-addmessage-from-a-trigger-to-a-visualforce-page/193241#193241